# TextInput Component suddenly not working in production Laravel 10 Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, laravel, forms, components, inertiajs

I got weird problem with TextInput Component from laravel reactjs.

I got the component from laravel breeze reactjs.
The problem is I cant type anything on the `<TextInput>`, but if i change it to <`input>` tag it works fine. It was working fine till today suddenly `<TextInput>` stop working, I didnt change anything because it comes with laravel and it works fine in local development exactly same code except I didnt do `npm run build` on local.

I already did `npm run build` and restart ssr server, no luck.

Here is one of the TextInput from Login.jsx

```
> <TextInput
>    id="email"
>    type="email"
>    name="email"
>    value={data.email}
>    className="mt-1 block w-full"
>    autoComplete="username"
>    isFocused={true}
>    handleChange={onHandleChange}
> 
> />
```

If I change it to this input, it works

```
<input
    type="email"
    name="email"
    id="email"
    value={data.email}
    className={
    'border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:ring-indigo-500 rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full'
    }
    autoComplete="username"
    required
    onChange={onHandleChange}
/>
```

It seems the component works again by making any changes to the component files, `TextInput.jsx` and `CheckBox.jsx` (was broken too). then run `npm run build` again.

Any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue today and solve it changing **ref** in TextInput.jsx

from:

```
ref={localRef}
```

To:

```
ref={input}
```

Comment: Looks like someone already fixed it in mainstream few days ago: https://github.com/laravel/breeze/commit/62c79d5d32962df5af2584ad92692a90eb69c10f